# Facebook video link does not open in web view java

Tags: java, android

this is a link to a facebook video https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=269637072007881

when i try to open it in my app web view it redirect to a different url and show me this error

`Webpage not available
The webpage at fb://fullscreen_video/269637072007881?loop=false&wtsid=wt_0p0MNje32ZvW5oQjV could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

if i try to open this url in other browser then it works perfectly.

this is my code for the webview:

```
            WebSettings webSettings = page.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            page.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {//it seems not setting webclient, launches
                //default browser instead of opening the page in webview
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                    if(blockedWebsites.contains(Utils.getBaseDomain(request.getUrl().toString()))){
                        Log.d("vdd", "URL : " + request.getUrl().toString());
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                .setMessage("Youtube is not supported according to google policy.")
                                .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    }
                                })
                                .create()
                                .show();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(final WebView webview, final String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            EditText urlBox = getVDActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_search_bar);
                            urlBox.setText(url);
                            urlBox.setSelection(urlBox.getText().length());
                            BrowserWindow.this.url = url;
                        }
                    });
                    view.findViewById(R.id.loadingProgress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    loadingPageProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    super.onPageStarted(webview, url, favicon);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    loadingPageProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadResource(final WebView view, final String url) {
                    Log.d("fb :", "URL: " + url);
                    final String page = view.getUrl();
                    final String title = view.getTitle();

                    new VideoContentSearch(getActivity(), url, page, title) {
                        @Override
                        public void onStartInspectingURL() {
                            Utils.disableSSLCertificateChecking();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinishedInspectingURL(boolean finishedAll) {
                            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(defaultSSLSF);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVideoFound(String size, String type, String link, String name, String page, boolean chunked, String website, boolean audio) {
                            videoList.addItem(size, type, link, name, page, chunked, website, audio);
                            updateFoundVideosBar();
                        }
                    }.start();
                }

                @Override
                public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (getActivity() != null) {
                        Log.d("VDDebug", "Url: " + url);
                        if (getActivity().getSharedPreferences("settings", 0).getBoolean(getString(R
                                .string.adBlockON), true)
                                && (url.contains("ad") || url.contains("banner") || url.contains("pop"))
                                && getVDActivity().getBrowserManager().checkUrlIfAds(url)) {
                            Log.d("VDDebug", "Ads detected: " + url);
                            return new WebResourceResponse(null, null, null);
                        }
                    }
                    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && getVDActivity() !=
                            null) {
                        if (MyApplication.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("settings", 0).getBoolean(getString
                                (R.string.adBlockON), true)
                                && (request.getUrl().toString().contains("ad") ||
                                request.getUrl().toString().contains("banner") ||
                                request.getUrl().toString().contains("pop"))
                                && getVDActivity().getBrowserManager().checkUrlIfAds(request.getUrl()
                                .toString())) {
                            Log.i("VDInfo", "Ads detected: " + request.getUrl().toString());
                            return new WebResourceResponse(null, null, null);
                        } else return null;
                    } else {
                        return shouldInterceptRequest(view, request.getUrl().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
            page.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    loadingPageProgress.setProgress(newProgress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                    super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
                    videoList.deleteAllItems();
                    updateFoundVideosBar();
//                    VisitedPage vp = new VisitedPage();
//                    vp.title = title;
//                    vp.link = view.getUrl();
//                    new HistorySQLite(getActivity()).addPageToHistory(vp);
                }
            });

            page.loadUrl(url);
            loadedFirsTime = true;
```

I expect this to open video in my app webview

Comment: Seems like facebook is redirecting you to an url with the "fb" scheme, most likely because it thinks you're viewing the page on a mobile phone, and wants to open the actual facebook app to view the video. What's the user agent of your webview?

Comment: I have the default user agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution to this problem. Just add this User-Agent to your web view :

```
        String MyUA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 8.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(MyUA);
```

it should now load the facebook video link into the webview